# Web Config for node js REST API inorder to host in windows server IIS

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-rest-api, nodejs

I'm first time creating REST API in node js. Can someone guide me what webconfig file should contain. I need to deploy this on windows server & I need to call this restapi from front end.

Comment: Is this a SharePoint project? Will the node js code be running on a SharePoint server?

Comment: Yes, We have UI - SharePoint. Angular page was integrated in the site. Now, I need to fetch the data from sql database. For that I am using node js and node js is installed on the server. The main concern is how webconfig file will be and how we will deploy in the server. I tried my level best to get the answer from the blogs but couldn't find.